# Bash: Running a function as sudo on remote host?

Tags: bash, function, ssh, sudo

I have the following example script, to run commands on a remote host.

The script accepts the remote host's password from user input which we can use to login as that user and I expect also pass to `sudo`.

The problem is, I can't seem to get the *runOnRemoteHostAsRoot* function inside the second function to run using `sudo`, which I need.

How do I get this to work?

Platform at both ends is Ubuntu 18 or 20.

```
#!/bin/bash

read SSHPASS
export SSHPASS

runOnRemoteHost() {
    # ...
    whoami
    # ...
}
# ...
sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "user@remotehost" "$(declare -f runOnRemoteHost); runOnRemoteHost" 2>&1
# ...


runOnRemoteHostAsRoot() {
    # ...
    whoami
    # ...
}
# ...
echo "${SSHPASS}" | sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "user@remotehost" "$(declare -f runOnRemoteHostAsRoot); sudo --stdin runOnRemoteHostAsRoot" 2>&1
# ...
```

Expected output:

```
user
root
```

Actual output:

```
user
[sudo] password for user: sudo: runOnRemoteHostAsRoot: command not found
```

Comment: `sudo` needs the name of an executable file, not a shell function, as its argument.

Comment: Okay. The question is though, how do I run the commands inside `runOnRemoteHostAsRoot` as root on the remote host?

Comment: Side note: Bash doesn't do lexical scoping, so nesting function definition doesn't somehow limit the scope of the inner function to the outer function.

Comment: You need to run a shell as root that executes the function. Something like `sudo sh -c "$(typeset -f runOnRemoteHost); runOnRemoteHost"`). Using `typeset` like this looks fragile, at best. Just define the function directly in the argument to `-c` or, better yet, define a script that you first copy to the remote host and then simply execute with `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo sh -c "$(typeset -f runOnRemoteHost); runOnRemoteHost"` results in:bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `sudo sh -c runOnRemoteHost () '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from [@Will](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269080) is helpful in this instance, using `sudo bash -c`, then declaring and running the function:

```
sudo bash -c "$(declare -f runOnRemoteHostAsRoot); runOnRemoteHostAsRoot"
```

We'll use that line after passing the password through `sshpass` for passwordless login, like this:

```
echo '${SSHPASS}' | sudo --stdin bash -c '$(declare -f runOnRemoteHostAsRoot); runOnRemoteHostAsRoot'`
```

So using this in the above example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read SSHPASS
export SSHPASS


runOnRemoteHost() {
    # ...
    whoami
    # ...
}
# ...
sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "user@remotehost" "$(declare -f runOnRemoteHost); runOnRemoteHost" 2>&1
# ...


runOnRemoteHostAsRoot() {
    # ...
    whoami
    # ...
}
# ...
sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "user@remotehost" "echo '${SSHPASS}' | sudo --stdin bash -c '$(declare -f runOnRemoteHostAsRoot); runOnRemoteHostAsRoot'" 2>&1
```

**Output:**

```
user
root
```